# Add / remove an ImageOverlay from Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, javascript

My goal is to add / hide an [L.ImageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#imageoverlay) image from my leaflet map on click. This code should work, but it only adds image and does not hide it on a following click.

```
var map = L.map('mainMap').setView([56.06, 92.500], 10);

function loadImage(e) {

    var imageUrl = 'data/kr1_cut.png',
        imageBounds = [[55.819224, 92.170872], [56.324808, 92.480904]],
        image = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds);
    // remove image layer if it already exists
    if (map.hasLayer(image)) {
        map.removLayer(image);
    }
    else {
        image.addTo(map);
    }
}

map.on('click', loadImage);
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First there is typo in the method call: it should be map.remov**e**Layer(image); This has been corrected.

Second thing is that layer should be defined outside of the function, otherwise a new layer is created at each function call:

```
var map = L.map('mainMap').setView([56.06, 92.500], 10);

var imageUrl = 'data/kr1_cut.png',
    imageBounds = [[55.819224, 92.170872], [56.324808, 92.480904]],
    image = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds);

function loadImage(e) {
  // remove image layer if it already exists
  if (map.hasLayer(image)) {
    map.removeLayer(image);
  } else {
    image.addTo(map);
  }
}

map.on('click', loadImage);
```

Comment: Leaflet's Guru :)

Answer (score 1):

You have typo here..

`map.removLayer(image);`

must be

`map.removeLayer(image);`